# Debian package for boost libraries

Tags: boost, package, debian

I want to create a debian package for boost libraries but it does not have a Makefile so i don't have an idea on how to create a package without the makefile. Can you guide me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

create makefile containing

```
all:
    ./bootstrap.sh
    ./b2 --build-dir=/tmp/boost-build
```

and anything else you require

Comment: I am using checkinstall to create the package. It is giving these errors.
 `    Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:
    ./bjam
    To adjust configuration, edit 'project-config.jam'.
    Further information:
    - Command line help: 
    ./bjam --help
    - Getting started guide: 
     http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html
     - Boost.Build documentation:
     http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/index.html
     ./b2 --build-dir=/tmp/boost-build
    make: ./b2: Command not found
    make: *** [install] Error 127
   Installation failed. Aborting package creation`

Comment: You... what? `bjam` indicates an old version. What version _are_ you building?

Comment: I am building boost version 1.42.0.

Comment: Hahaha. You might have mentioned this. Try bjam instead b2. (Also: upgrade! Boost 1.42 is from February 2010. That's ancient.)

Comment: It ran for a long time but still giving some errors.
`...failed updating 60 targets...
...skipped 12 targets...
...updated 734 targets...
make: *** [install] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation`
Can you brief me the steps for creating the whole package for boost from source, latest version will also work.

Comment: Hmm? Just `sudo apt-get build-dep libboost-all-dev` and `apt-get source --compile libboost-all-dev`? Why are you building packages if you can just use the existing ones?

Comment: I want to learn to create debian packages for these libraries. I have to implement it in a similar situation elsewhere.

Comment: If you want to learn, **don't** use `checkinstall`, because that's a hack for people who _don't want to have to learn_ how to package debs. Instead use `debuild` ([Intro Docs](https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging)) and perhaps `pbuilder` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_build_toolchain#Isolated_build_environments)